# Ctrl-C not working in visual studio 2019 when run as administrator

Tags: visual-studio, administrator

When Visual Studio runs as administrator, <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> shortcut keys are not working...

But when running VS normally - not as administrator - those shortcut keys work fine.

Comment: I faced same behavior when I open a solution by selecting directly (right click on recent solution in the Windows taskbar) with VS exec file set to be run as Administrator. But, If I open VS as administrator and then, open a solution, it works fine instead. (Version 16.11.29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this behaviour for all text-editor that I use in "Run as Administrator" mode.

The problem comes from a third-party application that uses a global hook (listens to a global hotkey) on those keystrokes (e.g. "Ctrl+C"). In my case it was a personal AutoHotKey/AutoIt3 script that was acting like a copy-paste board. But it could be some other application, or a malware.

If you disable such an application, the keyboard shortcuts Ctrl+C etc. should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I have some not the same issue, as an author, but i think maybe it is somehow related.

My case is : time to time i can't press **CTRL+C** in my **microsoft visual studio 2022 (community edition)** to **interupt terminal** execution (powershell). For separately opened terminal (outside of Visual Studio) works great, so something wrong with VS.

Only one fix i found is to disable in options->keyboard -> `edit.copy` hotkey and re-assign it from "Global" to "Text editor". So, it may affect other areas, but works fine in this case. What is the core issue here and how to fix it other way i did not found.

Maybe will be helpfull for anybody.

Answer (score 0):

In Tools=> Options => Keyboard => Check that Edit.Cut and Edit.Copy is bound to Ctrl+X and Ctrl+C

Or you can reset your settings using Reset button.

Comment: Ctrl-V should be bound to Edit.Paste. Ctrl-X is typically bound to Edit.Cut...

Comment: Edit.Cut and Edit.Copy is bound to Ctrl+X and Ctrl+C but not working... it happen when visual studio run as administrator. in normally run visual studio every thing is OK and shortcut keys work fine